# Lean4: How to construct an HEq between dependent functions?

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib, tactic

I have an extremely simple goal to prove:

```
HEq
  (fun px rd =>
    match px, rd with
    | Sum.inr _ppos, dir => dir)
  fun x => id
```

The reason the match happens is because the type of `px` is (PEmpty ⊕ t) and `dir` is a variable whose type depends on the value of `px`. So this is a heterogeneous equality between a dependent function that matches on its first argument *but doesn't use it* - it does so only to teach the compiler, and a non-dependent function (basically `const`).

I'm in tactic mode but cannot use `funext` here, because it seems to only apply to nondependent functions. I basically want to do a substitution, but don't know how.

#### Some more context

The biggest issue for me here is that I cannot even extract this goal
to the top level in any way. The most reduced version of this problem I could manage to extract is this:

```
def hmm (k : Type) (b : (Empty ⊕ k) → Type) : HEq
  (fun (px : Empty ⊕ k) (rd : b px) => match px with | Sum.inr ahh => rd )
  fun (x : Empty ⊕ k) (a : b x) => a :=
  by
  _
```

And this gives me a red squiggly line at the definition, which says this:

```
stuck at solving universe constraint
  imax 1 1 ?u.106314 =?= 1
while trying to unify
  (x : Empty ⊕ k) → b x → b x : Type
with
  (x : Empty ⊕ k) → b x → b x : Type
```

The problem arises from the `match` expression, which must somehow be introducing that ?u.106314 metavariable (if that is what it is). If I change this to:

```
def hmm (k : Type) (b : (Empty ⊕ k) → Type) : HEq
  (fun (px : Empty ⊕ k) (rd : b px) => rd)
  fun (x : Empty ⊕ k) (a : b x) => a :=
  by
  _
```

The error disappears (and the proof is trivial). When this goal first appeared in my code, it had an explicit `motive := ...` with a huge thing in the ... given to the `match` - that's why I think `match` is doing some universe shenanigans. So before I can prove the goal above, I need to make the statement of this heterogeneous equality type check, but can't even figure that out.

Here's a gist with all the code needed to recreate this goal: https://gist.github.com/amuricys/e6ad118dd28873c11779b64edf0268f9

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a MWE that we can paste into Lean?  (Turn your above goal into an example or theorem with a sorry for the proof.  Make sure it type checks.)  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry, I just added a lot more context and turned the goal into something you should be able to copy paste (what do you mean by MWE?). One problem before actually proving what I need though is that I can't even get this to type check, I'm stuck on some universe issue. Thanks for asking for more details.

Comment: To get things started I posted the answer I had earlier written.  I think it matches your current code close enough, but maybe not your original use case.

Answer (score 0):

(Wrote this before you updated your question.) I'm not sure where that goal came up, either in a real situation or just something you want to prove, but here is my best approximation to your situation:

```
def foo : (Sum Empty Nat) -> Nat
| Sum.inl e => e.elim
| Sum.inr n => n

def bar : (px : Sum Empty Nat) -> Fin (foo px) -> Fin (foo px)
| Sum.inl e, _ => e.elim
| Sum.inr _, dir => dir

def baz (x : Sum Empty Nat) : Fin (foo x) -> Fin (foo x) := id

example : bar = baz := by
  funext x n
  cases x with
  | inl e => exact e.elim
  | inr n => rfl
```

Notice that unlike your question, `bar` and `baz` are equal, not just `Heq`.  Moreover, I can't think of an interpretation where `Heq` is the right approach.  `Heq x y` are for when `x` and `y` have different-but-equal types, but in this case `bar` and `baz` have the same type `(x : Sum Empty Nat) -> Fin (foo x) -> Fin (foo x)`.  If `baz` instead had type `(x : Nat) -> Fin (foo x) -> Fin (foo x)` then these wouldn't be equal or Heq, since it is independent whether `Nat = Sum Empty Nat` in Lean, so you can't prove it.

Comment: This goal, with the HEq, is generated by a bunch of successive applications of the unfold -> simp tactics, a strategy I've found great success with elsewhere (I've only been doing Lean for about a week). I agree that with Eq the proof is quite simple and I'm not sure why this HEq is introduced. I'm sure the types of the arguments to the functions being equalized are different but it's hard to check because I can't extract the goal to the top level without it giving the type error above. I added all the code necessary for generating this error to the answer :)